# Shrink a Polygon as an Array of TPoint?

Tags: delphi, drawing, delphi-xe2, gradient, polygon

I'm utilizing `TCanvas.Polygon()` and would like to know how I can go about shrinking the size of the polygon, either if there is already a function for this, or how to write one. I have a type declared `TPoints: Array of TPoint;` and using it when calling `TCanvas.Polygon()`.

The trouble is, if I have to write this function, how does it recognize *which* direction each point needs to move (based on proportion to the rest of the polygon)?

For example, if I made an array of points (`TPoints`) to represent a 5 pointed star, and I needed to shrink it by 2 pixels, how would it know the direction to move the points?

The end intention is to implement a gradient for a polygon. There will be a loop to perform this, in which a) color is slightly adjusted, b) polygon points need to *shrink* by a few pixels, and c) polygon gets drawn (smaller than the previously drawn one); thus, creating a gradient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems to me you're looking for a way to do polygon offsetting - shrinking or expanding polygons by a specified number of units (pixels). My [Clipper Library](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) (written in Delphi, C++ and C#) does polygon offsetting. The 'direction the points move' (ie shrinking or expanding) will depend on the sign (positive vs negative) of the supplied 'delta' parameter to the [OffsetPolygons](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Routines/OffsetPolygons.htm) function.

Comment: Sweet. I never heard of this and now I have just gotta try it!

Answer (score 0):

The "classic" way to deal with this is a "transform matrix":

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Since you appear to be using Delphi XE2, have you looked at Firemonkey?  I believe that 2-D transforms are a standard part of the library:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Application_Platform
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Image_Effects
- http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/everything_xe_demo.html

Comment: That's nice to know, but a Delphi example would be better. There's also an issue that a `TPoint` is with Integers, no Decimals (meaning it's difficult to make calculations precise). Also, using Firemonkey means everything I do is Firemonkey, and that's not feasible in this case.

Comment: You mean a VCL example? (Firemonkey is still delphi!)

Comment: @WarrenP Yes, true, I didn't word that properly, actually this unit `clipper.pas` in the accepted answer doesn't rely on VCL, therefore can be used in FMX too :D